# how to sum multiple select fields vlaues, including subtracting negative numbers (to zero)

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to use several select fields to modify a numeric starting point. The select fields contain some negative numbers, so I want to add/subtract accordingly. I currently cannot do this with JQuery - so I'm trying to figure out how in straight javascript. I've gotten this far, but it's only for a single select field. For the same reason, I'm not sure if the negative numbers are going to subtract:

```
<select class="select1 selectables" id="dropdown-1" name="dropdown1"> 
 <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">select</option> 
 <option value="10">Choice 1 (plus 10)</option>
 <option value="-5">Choice 2 (minus 5)</option>
 <option value="60">Choice 3 (plus 60)</option> 
</select>
 <br />
<select class="select2 selectables" id="dropdown-2" name="dropdown2">    
 <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">select</option>
 <option value="5">Choice A (plus 10)</option>
 <option value="15">Choice B (minus 10)</option>
 <option value="15">Choice C (plus 15)</option> 
 </select>
 <br />
 <select class="select3 selectables" id="dropdown-3" name="dropdown3">    
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">select</option>
  <option value="5">Choice ii (- 35)</option>
 <option value="15">Choice ii (plus 15)</option>
 <option value="12">Choice iii (plus 12)</option> 
 </select>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var gg1 = new JustGage({
      id: "gg1",
      value: 0
      // removed elements, as this area isn't an issue
    });

document.getElementById('dropdown-1').addEventListener('change', (event) => {
      sum = 0;
      testvar = event.target.value;
      if (testvar > 0) {
        sum = (sum + testvar);
        alert(`up ${testvar}`);
      } else if (testvar < 1) {
        sum = (sum - parseInt(testvar, 10));
        alert(`down ${testvar}`);
      }
      gg1.refresh(sum);
      return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need special treatment for negative numbers. Simply add them as you would do with positive numbers. In the following snippet, I changed the values of negative options to their actual negative values. `calculateSum()` then calculates the sum from all boxes. Not just the changed one. Although an incremental version is definitely possible, there is no reason to do this with just three boxes. And this incremental variant is more likely to have bugs.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  document.getElementById('dropdown-1').addEventListener('change', calculateSum);
  document.getElementById('dropdown-2').addEventListener('change', calculateSum);
  document.getElementById('dropdown-3').addEventListener('change', calculateSum);
});

function calculateSum() {
  sum = 0;
  //iterate all three boxes
  for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
    var box = document.getElementById('dropdown-' + i);
    var value = parseInt(box.value);
    if (!isNaN(value))
      sum += value;
  }
  alert(sum);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<select class="select1 selectables" id="dropdown-1" name="dropdown1">
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">select</option>
  <option value="10">Choice 1 (plus 10)</option>
  <option value="-5">Choice 2 (minus 5)</option>
  <option value="60">Choice 3 (plus 60)</option>
</select>
<br />
<select class="select2 selectables" id="dropdown-2" name="dropdown2">
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">select</option>
  <option value="10">Choice A (plus 10)</option>
  <option value="-10">Choice B (minus 10)</option>
  <option value="15">Choice C (plus 15)</option>
</select>
<br />
<select class="select3 selectables" id="dropdown-3" name="dropdown3">
  <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected" value="">select</option>
  <option value="-35">Choice ii (- 35)</option>
  <option value="15">Choice ii (plus 15)</option>
  <option value="12">Choice iii (plus 12)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Three boxes is just for the sample I provided.. There would be quite a few more than that.. up to 10 - 15 fields. But this may still work for that many? I'll look over this in detail once I finish a meeting I'm in

Comment: Yes, also works with 15 boxes. I would consider switching to an incremental approach if you have more than 100 boxes.

Comment: Trying this now. It seems pretty straightforward, but I'm not getting anything. I don't see any syntax errors. Maybe there's some sort of scope issue, that I'm not seeing? I tried both alert(sum) and  gg1.refresh(sum);

Comment: I just realized something - not sure if this is relevant... When you say this is a way to sum all of the fields at once, does that mean it will only alert when all fields are completed? If that's the case, I do need incremental. The reason is because only one select field will be available at a time. That's a detail i didn't include, because I didn't think it would be relevant. My fault there.

Comment: What do you mean by available? Accessible from code? In this case, the incremental approach is easier than the general case where the user can update any of the boxes at any time. You just have to remember the previous sum from all previous fields and calculate the new sum by adding the current value (do not update the previous sum). The concept is similar to the one in the answer above except that you don't have a loop.

Comment: each select field is in a hidden div, only available to them when the previous field is completed. The user can go forward to the next field, only if they've made a choice. As they make the choice, an svg dial changes based on the number. The user then selects from the next field, further modifying the dial. I was exploring a simple method, just using innerhtml to write the number in a hidden div, so it's easy to access for each increment. None of this data gets put into any database, so I don't need to worry about code injection.